# Show records in SQL if count is more than 1

Tags: sql-server, count

I am creating a web app in which I need to print records which are appearing more than once.

I created this table

```
create table nameandinfo
(
    names nvarchar(40),
    contno nvarchar(40)
)
```

and inserted 3 records:

```
select * from nameandinfo
```

This is the sample data:

```
Ibibo   998test389
Nizam   959test681
Ibrahim 998test389
```

Now I count the data by (contno)

```
SELECT [contno], COUNT(*) contact
FROM nameandinfo
GROUP BY [contno]
```

and I get the following results:

```
9594857681  1
9987145389  2
```

I want to display only the rows for which the count is more than 1:

```
9987145389  2
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

Use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT [contno], COUNT(*) contact
FROM nameandinfo
GROUP BY [contno]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply any condition on Group By Column then you need to use Having as below

```
SELECT [contno], COUNT(*) cnt
FROM nameandinfo
GROUP BY [contno]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column is part of table that can be manipulated by where clause. When using Aggregate calculations such as sum and count , Having is used for filtering the data.

```
SELECT contno,COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM nameandinfo
GROUP BY contno
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```